# Take up doubts, a topic

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

When a teacher discusses something in the class, is it be okay to use "take up"?

> We'll **take up** this topic tomorrow.
>
> We'll **take up** X tomorrow.

And about "doubts" and "queries":

> We'll **take up** the doubts (or queries) tomorrow.

Do they sound okay? I think that "take up" is usually used for a particular issue.

Comment: Note that _doubts_ in this sense is (as far as I know) limited to Indian English.

Comment: And @ColinFine what about: "I'll take up your queries tomorrow."

Comment: @jonathanjo: that is what it means in many Englishes. It is clear that in Indian English it can mean "uncertainty" or "confusion".

Comment: @ColinFine ... happy to stand corrected, thanks.  https://amritt.com/india-english-dictionary/?term=doubt

Comment: It's perfectly fine. "Take up" means "start to work on". Though NB "doubt" is not used in this way in BrE and AmE, where it means "disbelief" not "confusion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, either of "take up" or "pick up" are often used in this situation.

> We'll **pick up** tomorrow from where we left off.

I think it sounds better to use an object with "take up"

> We'll take **this** up tomorrow from where we left off.
>
> Son: Dad, can we order pizza for lunch?
>   Father:  **Take it up** with your mother.  If it's fine with her it's fine with me.

I wouldn't use the word "doubts" in this case.  "Concerns" or "questions" sounds more natural:

> We're out of time so we'll take up your **concerns/questions** tomorrow.

I would be more likely to say "address", though:

> We're out of time so I'll **address** your concerns tomorrow.

Comment: And what about: "I'll take up your queries tomorrow."

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  Sure.  I would prefer "questions" but "queries" is fine.

Comment: Someone told me that "take up" absolutely and totally unnatural in this context ("questions" as well as "topics"), so I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I dont see anything wrong with it but that's just one opinion.

Comment: Hello Andrew. Does "quite a ways back" make sense in this context? **"We were stuck quite a ways back in traffic at this time yesterday."**

Comment: Actually a few people take the same bus each day. Yesterday they got to their stop late as they were held up in traffic at this time. But today, they got to their stop on time, and commented on this by saying that. (The sentence in bold in the reply above). **They  mean to say that they got to their stop on time today and yesterday they were stuck in traffic far from the bus stop.**